# Android app data, can the user access/edit it?

Tags: android, storage

I'm planning on developing an app and I don't want it to be 'online only' so I want to be able to store data internally on the users device, app data. Is this 'secure'? Or can people fiddle with the app data? Is there ANY secure offline way to store app data?

I tried reading http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#filesInternal which suggested it is secure, but somewhere else someone said rooted phones could disregard this. So is it secure or not? -If so is there any way to 'block the app' if the phone is rooted?

Comment: So how are important apps like banking/ping it protected? If apks can be decompiled...?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On a rooted phone the user can read the data.

With JellyBean Google tried to encrypt application data to prevent that from happening, but this feature is disabled for now because it broke too many apps.

Some ways of rooting the phone you can detect, for instance using [roottools](http://code.google.com/p/roottools/).
But there is no reliable way of detecting all the ways in which a phone could be rooted.

And even if you could make sure the phone is not rooted, what would prevent the user from rooting the phone after you downloaded the data?

Be aware that even if you don't download the data to a file: Using a rooted phone the attacker could still transmit the .dex file of your application to his PC. He can then decompile it (for example by using [dex2jar](http://code.google.com/p/dex2jar/) and [jd-gui](http://java.decompiler.free.fr/?q=jdgui)) to gain information of how to read the data from your server. 
Thus any info your app accesses from the server an attacker can potentially access as well.

Comment: Right so my APK is always vunerable too? :(

Comment: Yes. I'd like to think of an App as a kind of fancy webpage: you cannot trust the client (the client in this case being the phone your app is run on). An attacker has more rights on the client side than your app. A client might be modified in any way imaginable. So to answer your question about how banking apps are protected: most likely the same way banking web-pages are protected: by implementing the security server-side and not client-side.

Answer (score 3):

I have faced the same problem but found encryption is the only mechanism to handle the situation but ofcourse that increases burden on the device but if that is mandatory then only option is using Encryption or Steganography

Comment: Encryption/steganography is next to useless, because the user has access to the keys and algorithms as well as the data. At most, this adds work to the process of a user accessing the user's data, but it does not stop them. What you are describing is DRM, and there are two types of DRM: the ones that have been cracked and the ones that nobody has bothered to try to crack yet.

Answer (score 0):

> Is this 'secure'?

It is secure from other apps by default.

> somewhere else someone said rooted phones could disregard this

Users who root their phones can run apps with superuser permissions, and those apps can access any file on the device.

Hence, data on internal storage is not secure from the user, because it is the user's phone, not yours, and hence it is the user's data, not yours. Most users will not touch your data, but all users have the right to, if they take sufficient steps to do so.

> If so is there any way to 'block the app' if the phone is rooted?

There is no rock-solid way to determine if a phone is rooted.

Comment: If that's the case, what is the security that android can provide us to make valuable data from being misused?

Comment: @AndroSelva: If you do not want the user to "misuse" "valuable data", the only true solution is to not have users. The next-best workaround is to not store the data on the user's device, forcing the user to figure out how to download it for themselves, outside of your app.

Comment: What if my app is a offline based one?

Comment: @AndroSelva: Then you need to make the business decision to not worry about your data. Retailers are at greater risk of shoplifting than you are of having your data be pirated. The basic precautions that retailers take to stop shoplifting is equivalent to your using internal storage (vs. external storage, which does not require root to be accessed by users).